# Flex PopupManager Issue

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, popup

I have been working with pop-up manager lately and have an inconsistency issue.

This is created at application level, and then various levels are added to the application 
requiring the pop-up to be brought to the front.

roughly 1 in 5 times the grayish haze will appear (which renders the application unusable) as with any pop-ups, but doesn't display my pop-up window.

This is done within the component that i am popping-up and the application is the component that the pop-up is created on.

```
PopUpManager.addPopUp(this,application,true);
PopUpManager.bringToFront(this);
PopUpManager.centerPopUp(this);
```

Any clue how i can remove this inconsistency?

Comment: Edit the question and add the correct code and mention that you're calling it from the popup class.

Comment: When do the three lines above get called? On creation complete? On initialization?  Context would be helpful here.

Answer (score 1):

You're setting the model property of addPopUp to true.  That means that the application should always 'gray out', becoming unusable until the pop up is closed.

If you want the application to be usable while the pop-up is displayed, set the modal property to false:

```
PopUpManager.addPopUp(this,application,false);
```

Comment: He's not asking to remove the modal overlay. He's saying that only the overlay appears, and the pop up is not displayed.

Comment: @joshtynjala It seems like you're right.  I have no idea if my answer was before the question was edited (it doesn't look like it based on date stamps).  My memory is hazy; as this question over a year old.